# Please reopen this question immediately!

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/33671/if-we-are-saved-by-grace-then-why-are-we-getting-judged

The OP wanted to understand Christian theology. Please reopen this as soon as possible. Thank you.

Comment: There were 8 answers to the OP's question and they were invited to chat to discuss one answer further, which they did. Why does this need to be re-opened?

Comment: If you think a question should be re-opened, you should give a clear case for why it is within site guidelines, and specifically why the close reason is no longer valid. You have made no attempt to do this, which, along with your wording, makes your reopen request appear to be demanding and unwarranted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Under current site guidelines, a theology question must specify a denomination or other group whose perspective they want.  There is no such thing as (universal) "Christian Doctrine."  So, the question was properly closed.